# Task Parallel Library - running dependent tasks

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

Dot Net Version = 4.
Language = C#

I am pretty much a novice in c# so please consider me a beginner :).

What i am trying to do: 
Create a WPF app that displays computer uptime information in a datagrid
Get computernames from a listbox and run a "Ping" function using TPL which returns a status property indicating whether the computer was alive or unreachable.

If the status property from a task returned "success" then i would run an "uptime" function to get the uptime from the server and add it to an observable collection which will serve as input to a datagrid.

I am currently having trouble running the second task that is - "Uptime" function which seems to be freezing the UI. I am not sure if i should be running the "uptime" function inside a "continuewith" block.
Also i would like to be able to cancel out of all operations when required.

CODE:

```
        private void btn_Uptime_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

        foreach (var item in Listbox1.Items)
        {

            string host = item.ToString();

            // Start Parallel execution of tasks
            var compute = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                return PingHost(host);

            }, tokenSource.Token);

            tasks.Add(compute);

            if(compute.Result.Status.ToLower() == "success")    
            {
                //Need to run the getuptime function based on the "success" result from each compute task 
                //without freeqing the UI.
                WMIHelper.GetUptime(compute.Result.ComputerName); 
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
       ......
        tasks.Add(compute);
        compute.ContinueWith(c=>
        {
            if(c.Result.Status.ToLower() == "success")
            Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>WMIHelper.GetUptime(compute.Result.ComputerName));
        });
```

Comment: Or prefer `TaskScheduler.FromSynchronizationContext()`

Comment: @ethicallogics - thanks for the reply. I moved the if inside the continuewith block and then ran the "Getuptime" within a new task and it seems to run.  So i am i correct in thinking that "continuewith" is just a container for a new task and does not automatically run any code placed inside of it in async?

Comment: The problem was in compute.Result when you call Result on Task the thread Waits untill the Task is not completed so you was calling it on UI thread so your UI was freezing. ContinueWith is called when the Task Completed and that task is passed to it. for more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx